# rails simple_form Controller#create as HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a problem with a simple_form_for,
if I select many number in my form, I have a rollback, it is not possible to validate.

I have this error:

```
Processing by SudokusController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Qafet...", "sudoku"=>{"number"=>"1, 2"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

but in Terminal (rails c) it's work....

I can not solved this:

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for @sudoku do |f| %>  
<% (1..9).each do |x| %>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sudoku[number][]" id="optionsCheckbox<%= x %>" value="<%= x %>" />
          <%= x %>
        </label>
      </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

sudoku.rb:

```
validates :number, presence: true
```

in sudoku controller:

```
def sudoku_params
    params.require(:sudoku).permit(:number)
end
```

In my db

Sudoku (number:string)

Tanks for your help

Comment: The part of the code which you posted as error is not error actually. Please post the error in the  question.

Comment: Hello and tanks for your time, The error is in the question but if you have need anything else I do not know what post more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the controller to:

```
def sudoku_params
    params.require(:sudoku).permit(number:[])
end
```

I solved my problem

Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

The line `"sudoku"=>{"number"=>"1, 2"}` of your params doesn't look right for a list of checkboxes. The problem might be in the way you are printing out your checkbox HTML. Try to update it to this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sudoku[number][]" id="optionsRadios<%= x %>" value="<%= x %>" />
```

PS. There are spaces and the field name has been changed.

Comment: Hello, tanks but not work, I have the same problem...space is in the stakoverflow not in my code ...sorry...

Comment: Could you please add rendered HTML of those 9 checkboxes?

Comment: I have post the html.

Comment: Has your `params` changed after this? I've just checked and it should now be `"sudoku"=>{"number"=>[1, 2]}`. Also, you can check which validations are not passing with `@sudoku.errors.full_messages`.

Comment: Then, show us the validation error text. I provided a code in previous comment.

Comment: yes i have this "sudoku"=>{"number"=>[1, 2]} but error is same. but 
for check validations are not passing with @sudoku.errors.full_messages. i post in the controller in create?

Comment: I have this error: undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass